# UIWebView in UIScrollView and touch notifications

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have view controller with following view hierarchy:

```
UIView
 '- UIScrollView
      '- UIWebView
      '- UIWebView
      '- ... more UIWebViews
```

UIScrollView has paging enabled and each page contains one UIWebView. UIScrollView occupies entire screen, UIWebView as well.

Now my problem is that I need to detect touches on entire screen. I guess that UIScrollView somehow eats most of those (and since UIWebView contains scroll view as well, things got even more complicated).

I tried subclassing each of those views and tried both touchesBegan and tap gesture recognizer but nothing. All I was able to get was very unreliable gesture recognizer on UIWebView, it worked once in 20 taps, very random and very weird.

How should I solve this? I need touchesBegan and touchesEnded or tap gesture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to find an alternative way of building your UI. Apple explicitly [recommend against embedding scroll views inside scroll views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922):

> You should not embed UIWebView or
>   UITableView objects in UIScrollView
>   objects. If you do so, unexpected
>   behavior can result because touch
>   events for the two objects can be
>   mixed up and wrongly handled.

Without knowing what you're trying to achieve it's difficult to be able to suggest a valid alternative. Tabs? A swipe gesture at the bottom of the screen? Links inside the webviews?

Comment: I don't think there is other way how to build my UI. I need UIWebView to render formated text and I need scroll view to flip between those web view pages. I want to detect touch on left and right side of screen to be able to go next/prev page (complementing standard scroll view's swipe functionality)

Comment: Looks like you were right about mixing scroll views. When I disable user interaction on webview, everything works fine. On the other side I lose copy functionality which would be nice to have (I don't use links or any other interactive stuff)

Comment: I want to keep webview "fullscreen" and have touch react to whole screen (left half to move to prev, right half to move to next page)

Comment: Sure, but something is going to have to give. Do you need a full UIWebView? How about something like: https://github.com/simonmaddox/SMFancyText

Comment: That SMFancyText looks very promising, it would solve my problems. I am going to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you need to be careful with the touch events so that scrollview does not handle touches intended for webview.

Import line on the code below is  [[[wv1 subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];

```
for (NSString *link in links) {
    UIWebView *wv1 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    NSURL *aurl = [site getUrl:link local:YES];
    [wv1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aurl]];
    [[[wv1 subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [scrollView addSubview:wv1];
    [wv1 release];  
}
```